# Questions about Rudin's proof of the Riesz representation theorem (R&CA)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I think I've managed to digest most of the proof, but there are still a couple irregularities here and there I'm not $100$% clear on.
[image]

1. Where does the estimate $f(x)<y_i+\epsilon,x\in V_i$ come from? I realise why a $V_i$ of such measure must exist (follows from the definition and the infimum property), but it isn't clear to me why the $V_i$ should have this additional property.
   [image]

2. Where does the final estimate $\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\epsilon)\mu(E_i)\leq\int_Xfd\mu$ come from? My reasoning was $s=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\epsilon)\chi_{E_i}$ is a simple function and, since $y_i-\epsilon<f(x)$ on $E_i$ (follows from $f(x)\in (y_{i-1},y_i]$ and $|y_i-y_{i-1}|<\epsilon$), we get $(y_i-\epsilon)\chi_{E_i}\leq f$ on $E_i$ and hence $s\leq f$ on $K$ (the support of $f$, which is equal to the disjoint union of the $E_i$). If $s\leq f$ on $K^c$ as well we'd get the inequality by the monotony of the integral, but $s|_{K^c}=0$ and it is in no way presupposed that $f$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: Choose an open set $W_i$ containing $E_i$ such that $\mu (W_i) <\mu (E_i)+\frac {\epsilon } n$ and take $V_i=W_i \cap f^{-1}(-\infty, y_i+\epsilon)$.

Second question: If $x$ is not in any of the $E_i$'s then $x$ is not in $K$ (which is the support of $f$) so $f(x)=0$. Hence, $\int f d\mu=\sum \int_{E_i} fd\mu \geq \sum (y_i-\epsilon)\mu(E_i)$.

Comment: The bit about $K$ was dumb by me, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{x\mid f(x) < y_i + \varepsilon\}$ is open ($f$ is continuous and you can also write it as $f^{-1}[(-\infty, y_i+\varepsilon)]$). $E_i$ is by definition a subset of it (as for all $x \in E_i$ we have $f(x) \le y_i$) and so we approximate $E_i$ from the outside by outer regularity by some open subset $O$ with $\mu(O) < \mu(E_i) + \frac{\varepsilon}{n}$ and take the intersection $V_i = O \cap f^{-1}[(-\infty, y_i+\varepsilon)]$ and this is still open and has the wanted extra property.

For the last part I see no problem, the simple function argument is fine, and the integral is $0$ outside $K$ anyway so the simple function is  a lower bound for the integral by definition IMO.